# Problems with internet access via modem . Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: usb, upgrade, updates, 15.10, wvdial

I already connect to the internet using a modem SmartFren CE628 but I have not been able to access the internet.

For example `ping 8.8.8.8`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, don't know how to solve it permanently, but what I do to connect to the internet is going to System Settings -> Network -> Mobile Network[or sth like that, I don't have english software], then in the select you choose to add new connection proceed normally. It should connect to the internet, and you should be able to ping 8.8.8.8